# How to use multiple OIDC providers in a blazor WebAssembly Project

Tags: authentication, blazor, keycloak, openid-connect, webassembly

I am in the process of creating a Blazor WebAssembly app that uses multiple OIDC configurations to allow the user to authenticate.

I want to use different realms in keycloak that I can select in the interface. Each realm can be used for authentication.

I used the following configuration

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using BlazorApp4;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("t2", options.ProviderOptions);
    builder.Configuration.Bind("t1", options.ProviderOptions);
});
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

In my appsettings.json I have the following configuration:

```
{
  "t1": {
    "Authority": "http://localhost:8080/realms/t1",
    "ClientId": "client"
  },
  "t2": {
    "Authority": "http://localhost:8080/realms/t1",
    "ClientId": "client"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the last entered config always "wins".

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action"  />

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string? Action { get; set; }
}
```

I use the default generated Authentication.razor page.

The login itself works fine, I am redirected to the Keycloak login page and can log in.

Is there any way I can choose here which page I want to be redirected to?

Tried different ways of configuring the oidc clients but nothing works.